# resolved conflicts after git pull

Tags: git, github

But what to do next?

```
$ git pull
Auto-merging views/upload_photo.handlebars
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in views/upload_photo.handlebars
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

James@DESKTOP-8VLS7EG MINGW64 ~/Documents/project (master|MERGING)
$ git merge --abort

James@DESKTOP-8VLS7EG MINGW64 ~/Documents/project.my (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        views/upload_photo_BACKUP_4736.handlebars
        views/upload_photo_BASE_4736.handlebars
        views/upload_photo_LOCAL_4736.handlebars
        views/upload_photo_REMOTE_4736.handlebars

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What should I do? if I do git pull again my resolved conflicts files will be reset.

Comment: curious to know why did you run git merge --abort ?

Comment: @root545 because when I resolve the conflict the terminal has no response.

Comment: what do you mean by no response?  how are you resolving conflicts ?

Comment: @root545 I solve it using sublime, I saved the file, the terminal has no response.

Comment: can you run git log HEAD..origin/master and paste that here at lease the first few commits ?

Comment: yes, what's next?

Comment: what is the git log output ?

Comment: does it matter? my previous commits.

Comment: Here is what I am thinking. Someone has pushed other commits to the remote branch . meanwhile you have done your local commit . That is why it is saying that your branch has diverged by  1 and 2 different commits. Can you check if the merge conflict you resolved is still there ? because if you ran git merge-abort it should bring your branch to the old state before you did git pull.

Answer (score 10):

## TL;DR: you have three options

> What should I do? if I do git pull again my resolved conflicts files will be reset.

Your three options are:

- Use `git merge` (which is what `git pull` is trying to do).  Resolve the conflict and commit.  The "resolve the conflict" part is the hard part.  See lots of other commentary on doing merges, including other SO postings, e.g., [Merging with git - how do I figure out where the 'new' code ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40558654/1256452)
- Use `git rebase` (which you can tell `git pull` to do instead of `git merge`).  That will leave you with exactly the same problem, which you will have to solve the same way: resolve the conflict and commit.  (See below.)
- Give up. :-)  Not a very attractive option, but it *is* an option!  See below.

## The long answer

The `git pull` command first runs (a minor variant of) `git fetch`, then runs `git merge`.  (Or, you can tell `git pull` to run `git rebase` as its second step.)

As [root545 said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558949/resolved-conflicts-after-git-pull#comment68355912_40558949), someone else has pushed some commits—two of them, to be exact.  Your `git fetch` step brings those commits into your repository.  Meanwhile, your own commits (or commit, singular, since you have just the one) also remains in your repository.

I don't know *who* made those other two commits, but let's just assume it's some guy named Bob.  The *way* he made those commits was to: (1) fetch, then merge or rebase if necessary—i.e., `git pull`—everyone else's work into *Bob*'s repository, then (2) make his two new commits, then (3) `git push` his new work out to the Git on origin.  He did all three of these steps *while* you were doing your work.  The crucial part of the equation is that he did step 3 *before* you managed to `git push` your commit to origin.

You are now one commit *ahead* of Bob, but also two commits *behind* Bob.  This would be true whether or not Bob beat you to step 3—but because he *did* win that particular race, he got his stuff into the Git repository on origin before you could get your stuff there.  Fixing up the mess is now *your* problem.  If you had done step 3 (`git push origin master`) before Bob did his step 3, this would be *his* problem.  (If you're not *allowed* to push, well, you'll *never* do step 3, and you'll *always* be getting behind like this.  That's not necessarily a problem, but read on.)

## How the overall process works

Let's take a moment to draw what Git sees at this point.  Git likes to work from *commits*, like the one you made, and the two Bob made.  Commits represent a complete snapshot: all the files you need (or Bob needs) together in one repository, in the form it was when you (or Bob) said:  *This is good, this will all work.*  You make each snapshot by running `git commit`, which turns whatever is in your "index" (the thing you use `git add` to update) into the next commit.

You and Bob both started with a *common* snapshot (commit), which you<sup>1</sup> called `master`, which you got from `origin`, so that you also called this common snapshot `origin/master`.  This commit was at the tip of some long chain of commits:

```
... <- o <- o <- o   <-- master, origin/master
```

Each commit in this chain, represented by a round `o`, points "backwards" to a previous commit.  These backwards arrows are mostly just annoying though, so let's just use connecting lines to draw this.  The fact that one commit is earlier is obvious, because we drew it to the left.  And, because the current tip is pretty important to what we're going to do next, let's give it a star:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- master, origin/master
```

Now *you* make your commit (meanwhile Bob is making his commits, but we won't worry about that yet).  It's a *new* commit, so it points back to the previous tip of `master`, which your Git still remembers for you as `origin/master`, so now the drawing looks like this:

```
             A   <-- master
            /
...--o--o--*     <-- origin/master
```

I've given this one a one-letter name so that we can talk about it: "commit `A`".

Now let's take a look at Bob's work.  He doesn't have your `A`; he couldn't possibly; you have not shared it yet.  He had this instead at the beginning of his work:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- master, origin/master
```

i.e., the same starting setup.  But he made his *two* commits and now has:

```
...--o--o--*     <-- origin/master
            \
             B--C   <-- master
```

Now Bob does his `git push` step.

What's on `origin` is, at this point, the original chain, ending in `--o--*`.  His Git talks to a Git on `master` and says "here, have commits `B` and `C` and then, if you like, please set your (origin's) `master` to point to `C`?"  And, since the Git on origin knows and likes Bob at least a bit, *and* `C` points back to `B` which points back to `*`, the origin Git says:  "OK, sure, I'll make my `master` point to commit `C`.  `C` remembers `B` and `B` remembers `*` so this just *adds new stuff*."  So now origin has the same chain as Bob has, and origin's `master` points to commit `C`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Bob no doubt also calls *his* `master`, but we don't need to care; that's up to Bob.  What matters to *you* is what winds up in the Git repository on origin.  That's where you talk to the rest of the world.  The setup on origin is your convenient meeting-place.  That's what a central repository is all about: it's the market square, where everyone gets together to exchange commits.

---

#### Enter `git fetch`

At this point, *you* run `git pull` which runs `git fetch` which contacts the Git on origin.  Your Git obtains commits `B` and `C` and puts them in *your* repository, and your Git adjusts *your* `origin/master` to point to `C`, because this is now what your Git remembers from `origin`.  So *your* repository now looks like this:

```
             A     <-- master
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             B--C   <-- origin/master
```

**You have all three new commits.  In fact, you're the *only one* with all three.**  That's why it's now *your job* to fix this up.

## Fixing the mess

You have two options for fixing this, plus, of course, a third option: don't bother fixing it at all.

The standard option is to use `git merge`, which `git pull` runs for you.  The second, and often better option, is to use `git rebase`, which is more complicated in general.

The third option is the easiest.  You don't ever *have* to merge, you can just keep on developing and diverge forever.  You never pick up any of Bob's—or anyone else's—new work, ever, regardless of what you do pick up, if anything, from the Git on origin.  (In this case, you might want to stop calling this `master` and start calling it `jessie` instead.  The name is not all that important, but by giving it your own name, instead of `master`, you may be able to remember better what you were doing, if you have to put this aside for a while and then come back to it.)

The advantages and disadvantages of this third approach should be obvious: it's really easy, it takes no work at all on your part, but of course you never benefit from other people's work either.  So let's say you decide not to go this way.  How will you combine *your* work with *their* work?  Again, the options Git gives you are `merge` and `rebase`.

#### Merging

Merging is, in fact, the simpler approach.  It records exactly what happened, to whom, and when.  The merge commit becomes a sort of glue: "I had my work, and you had yours, and then I combined them."  To do a merge, you—somehow—*combine* your work and Bob's work, and make what Git calls a *merge commit*.  You figure out how to get your new snapshot `A` to work with Bob's `C`, and make a new snapshot from that.  Let's assume the "somehow" is pure magic, and draw the result:

```
             A------M   <-- master
            /      /
...--o--o--*      /
            \    /
             B--C   <-- origin/master
```

This new commit `M` is your new "merge commit": the one `git log` will show as `merge branch 'origin/master'` or `merge branch 'origin' of ...` depending on exactly what arguments you give to `git merge`.  We might want to redraw this a bit to look like this, as it's a bit less messy:

```
...--o--o--*--A---M  <-- master
            \    /
             B--C   <-- origin/master
```

If you then `git push` this successfully—i.e., the Git over on origin knows and likes you at least a little bit, *and* your `A` and `M` just *add to its commits*<sup>2</sup>—then what will happen is that the Git on origin will move *its* master as well, and your Git will update your remembered `origin/master` and you'll get this:

```
...--o--o--*--A---M  <-- master, origin/master
            \    /
             B--C
```

That's what `git merge` is all about: you join *your* work with *someone else's* work, make a merge commit, and probably push the result.

---

<sup>2</sup>Since `M` points back to both `A` *and* `C`, this really does just add to the commits stored in the Git on origin.  Well, it does *as long as your `git push`, step 3, finishes before anyone else's `git push`.*  It's your job not only to merge or rebase, but also to beat the others to pushing, if you're going to push.  If you lose this race you get to try again!—though perhaps from a better starting point this time.  Your existing merge or rebase remains yours, and that's probably a *much* better starting point now.

Note that if you *never* push, you will certainly have to merge or rebase again in the future.  But the work you just did gets you that same "much better starting point" for next time.  If you merge or rebase often, you probably won't have too much work to do each time.

---

#### Merging leaves a messy history

Assuming you succeed at this, now *you* are ahead of *Bob*, and *he's* going to have to pick up *your* new work.  In fact, that's true of everyone else using the Git on origin to share work: they all must pick up your merge.

Over time, people—no matter who—doing lots of merges causes lots of this pattern of commits that form little branchlets, followed by merges.  The value—if there is *any* value—of all the merge commits is that it shows *exactly who did what, and when, and how they glued it all together*.  The drawback is, it shows *exactly who did what, and when, and how they glued it together*, and most of the time, it's only the "who did what" part that really matters.

The "and when" part grows less important every day.  A year from now, who cares whether you and Bob worked at exactly the same time?  Wouldn't the result be the same if you just did everything *after* Bob finished?

Worse, the "how they glued it all together" becomes nothing but a distraction.  *If* you *had* started just after Bob finished, you'd still get the same result, right?  And then there would *be* no glue-it-together step at all.  You would have a commit history that looks like this:

```
...--o--o--*--B--C--A--o--o--...
```

which, if you find yourself coming back to it later, is *much* easier to deal with.

#### Rebasing

This is what `git rebase` is for.  Suppose we go back to the setup you have just after you run `git fetch`:

```
             A     <-- master
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             B--C   <-- origin/master
```

What if you could, now, easily take your commit `A`, copy it to a slight variant—let's call this `A'`—and have `A'` come *after* commit `C`?  That would look like this:

```
             A     <-- ???
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             B--C   <-- origin/master
                 \
                  A'   <-- master
```

This is what `git rebase` is all about.  What makes `git rebase` more complicated than `git merge` is that if you have *more than one* commit, it has to copy *all* of them.  That is, suppose you had instead:

```
             D--E--F   <-- master
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             B--C      <-- origin/master
```

You would need to get:

```
             D--E--F   <-- ???
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             B--C        <-- origin/master
                 \
                  D'-E'-F'   <-- master
```

As implied by the `<-- ???`, we'll soon just forget that there ever was an original, and drop all the little tick-marks and call these `A` or `D--E--F`.  The nice thing about this is that once you get it all working and `git push` successfully, when you come back to all this in a year or however long, you have:

```
...--o--o--*--B--C--D--E--F--o--o--
```

or the same with `A`, which is probably what we would all like to have in a year or however long.

It *is* more work up front.  Git automates most of the work, but it's more confusing when it goes wrong—and if you get a conflict from `git merge` on your one `A` commit, you will get *the same* conflict on a `git rebase` of that commit.  It's up to you whether to switch to `git rebase`.  (It really is usually better, and you'll have to solve exactly the same:

> ```
> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in views/upload_photo.handlebars
> ```

either way.)